# Ошибка при вычислении процентов (Калькулятор на tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Пишу калькулятор на python tkinter и столкнулся с такой проблемой:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\viksl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\viksl\Desktop\Calc.py", line 29, in calculate
    value = float(value)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '56%'
```

Я пытался по разному решить проблему, но ничего не получилось. Сама проблема в этой части кода:

```
def calculate():
    value = calc.get()
    if value[-1] in '+-/*':
        value = value + value[:-1]
    elif value[-1] in '%':
        value = float(value)
        value = str(value/100)
    calc.delete(0, tk.END)
    calc.insert(0, eval(value))
```

Сам код:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def info2():
    messagebox.showinfo('Об авторе', 'Программу выполнил студент группы 19-ВТ2 \nСлепчатов Виктор')
        
def add_digit(digit):
    value = calc.get()
    if value[0] == '0' and len(value) == 1:
        value = value[1:]
    calc.delete(0, tk.END)
    calc.insert(0, value+digit)

def add_operation(operation):
    value = calc.get()
    if value[-1] in '+-*/%':
        value = value[:-1]
    elif '+' in value or '-' in value or '/' in value or '*' in value or '%' in value:
        calculate()
        value = calc.get()
    calc.delete(0, tk.END)
    calc.insert(0, value+operation)

def calculate():
    value = calc.get()
    if value[-1] in '+-/*':
        value = value + value[:-1]
    elif value[-1] in '%':
        value = float(value)
        value = str(value/100)
    calc.delete(0, tk.END)
    calc.insert(0, eval(value))
'''
def add_perc():
    value = calc.get()
    value = float(value)
    value = str(value/100)
    calc.delete(0, tk.END)
    calc.insert(0, eval(value))
'''
def clear():
    calc.delete(0, tk.END)
    calc.insert(0, 0)

def make_digit(digit):
    return tk.Button(text=digit, bd=5, font=('Arial', 13), command=lambda: add_digit(digit))

def make_operation_button(operation):
    return tk.Button(text=operation, bd=5, font=('Arial', 13), command=lambda: add_operation(operation))

def make_calc_button(operation):
    return tk.Button(text=operation, bd=5, font=('Arial', 13), command=calculate)

def make_clear_button(operation):
    return tk.Button(text=operation, bd=5, font=('Arial', 13), command=clear)

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry = (f"240x280+100+200")
win.title('Калькулятор')

calc = tk.Entry(win, justify=tk.RIGHT, font=('Arial', 15), width=15)
calc.insert(0,'0')
calc.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, stick='we', padx=5)

avtor = tk.Button(text='Об авторе', bd=5, width=15, command=info2)
avtor.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=3, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)
'''
per = tk.Button(text='%', bd=5, font=('Arial', 13), command=add_perc)
per.grid(row=5, column=3, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)
'''
make_digit('1').grid(row=1, column=0, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)
make_digit('2').grid(row=1, column=1, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)
make_digit('3').grid(row=1, column=2, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)
make_digit('4').grid(row=2, column=0, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)
make_digit('5').grid(row=2, column=1, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)
make_digit('6').grid(row=2, column=2, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)
make_digit('7').grid(row=3, column=0, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)
make_digit('8').grid(row=3, column=1, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)
make_digit('9').grid(row=3, column=2, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)
make_digit('0').grid(row=4, column=0, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)

make_operation_button('+').grid(row=1, column=3, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)
make_operation_button('-').grid(row=2, column=3, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)
make_operation_button('*').grid(row=3, column=3, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)
make_operation_button('/').grid(row=4, column=3, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)
make_operation_button('%').grid(row=5, column=3, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)

make_calc_button('=').grid(row=4, column=2, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)
make_clear_button('C').grid(row=4, column=1, stick='wens', padx=5, pady=5)

win.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=60)
win.grid_columnconfigure(1, minsize=60)
win.grid_columnconfigure(2, minsize=60)
win.grid_columnconfigure(3, minsize=60)

win.grid_rowconfigure(1, minsize=60)
win.grid_rowconfigure(2, minsize=60)
win.grid_rowconfigure(3, minsize=60)
win.grid_rowconfigure(4, minsize=60)
win.grid_rowconfigure(5, minsize=60)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Вам же ясно написали: "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '56%'". Даже строчку указали, в которой это происходит: "line 29, in calculate  value = float(value)" Ну так исправляйте. Или до 29 самостоятельно посчитать не умеете?  Какую помощь при этом всем вы ждете получить на форуме???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как видно из описания ошибки, программа пытается перевести строку `'56%'` в вещественный тип данных, однако из-за знака процента данный процесс прерывается.

Насколько я понял, Вы можете просто взять часть числа без знака процента и затем  дальше разбираться с ним, правильно? Для этого, по аналогии с веткой с `+-*/`, берём все символы строки, кроме последней:

```py
def calculate():
    value = calc.get()
    if value[-1] in '+-/*':
        value = value + value[:-1]
    elif value[-1] in '%':
        value = float(value[:-1]) # 56% -> 56, ошибки нет
        value = str(value/100)
    calc.delete(0, tk.END)
    calc.insert(0, eval(value))
```